# Let JOIN statement be executed in remote query in MSSQL (Azure)

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

In our database we are querying multiple remote database tables in a single query and joining the resulting data locally. As we therefore have to transfer a lot of data from the two remote tables before joining the query executes for a rather long time (for "big" users approx. 45 seconds atm.).

During research I found that we can improve this, by letting the JOIN statement be executed on the remote database and then only request the resulting data from the remote server.

The "expensive" query is the following:

```
SELECT
            DISTINCT c.CustomerID,
            c.Field6
        FROM
            UniLevelTree tree
            INNER JOIN Customer c ON tree.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
            AND c.CompanyID = 12345678
            AND c.CustomerStatusTy = 1
            INNER JOIN redactedRemoteWebContext.PartnerMilestone milestone ON milestone.PartnerID = c.CustomerKey
            INNER JOIN Orders orders ON orders.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
            AND orders.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
            AND orders.OrderDate >= '2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z'
            AND orders.OrderDate <= '2023-04-20T00:00:00.000Z'
            INNER JOIN Period p ON p.StartDate >= '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'
            AND p.StartDate <= '2023-04-30T00:00:00.000Z'
            AND p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
        WHERE
            tree.Lft >= @Lft
            AND tree.Lft <= @Rgt
            AND tree.CompanyID = 1858
            AND milestone.MilestoneKey IN(
                'Earnings10000',
                'Title20',
                'TPV50000',
                'PPV10000'
            )
            AND orders.isCommissionable IN(1)
            AND orders.OrderTy IN(5, 5, 8)
            AND orders.CommissionableVolume >= 0
            AND orders.CommissionableVolume <= 5000
            AND milestone.AchievedDate >= '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'
            AND milestone.AchievedDate <= '2023-04-30T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Out of the referenced tables, the following are from the remote tables:

- Customer
- UniLevelTree
- PartnerMilestone
- Orders
- Period

Please find attached the query plan of this query:
[image: Query Plan]

As you can see, the JOIN is executed on the local database server with data received from two remote queries.

**How can I enforce the JOIN to be executed on the remote server and only the resulting data be transmitted to the local DB? Is there some way of sub-querying on the remote table?**

So far I've tried:

- Using REMOTE query hint: Sadly not applicable for the SQL Server Version (Azure SQL)

Comment: you can use openquery to go against same server and do the join between the remove tables. i don't think you can do whole thing remotely though. Sometimes what i use is to build every joined ID from local server and put it as where into the OPENQUERY

Comment: Good call! When I try to execute the query with an OPENQUERY it says that the version of SQL Server does not support it :/

Comment: OK, then create a view on the remote server that does the joins you need and then query from the view, although it might still suck a bit :( I really hate how much azure is restricted for proper SQL